# How to load more than one data in a view from the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know if it's possible to load more than one data, from the controller to the view.

This is what I've tried:

```
$this->load->view('backend',$result,$data);
```

as well as:

```
$this->load->view('backend',$result);
$this->load->view('backend',$data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an ideal example for what you've tried to achieve

```
$view_variables['result'] = $result;
$view_variables['data'] = $data;

$this->load->view('backend',$view_variables);
$this->load->view('backend')
```

in view you can use result and data:

```
$result;
$data;
```